# react-table check data presence before useTable hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I am new in react-table, actually I am trying to rewrite crappy react-bootstrap-table2 into react-table.

I am fetching data with axios and then, in my react-table component I am retrieving then with useSelect.Then I use them in useTable hook, but

```
import React from "react";
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {useTable} from "react-table";

function Table() {

let testsData = useSelector(state => 
state.fetchTestsData.testsData);
console.log("testData to show in table ", testsData);
testsData = !(testsData === null || testsData.length === 0) ?  [];


const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
        {
            Header: '1',
            accessor: '1column',
        },
        {
            Header: '2',
            accessor: '2column',
        },
    ],
    []
);

const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
} = useTable({columns, testsData});


const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
} = useTable({columns, testsData});
```

there is a moment, when there are no data. I cannot put useTable in if condition cause it's hook. How can I check my data for existance? react-table gives me TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

p.s I updated the above snippet. It still gives me an error.

Even if I declare testsData = []; and pass it to useTable- it gives an error

Comment: Give `testData` a default value somewhere in your code. Is it stored somewhere in state?

Comment: @Drew Reese hmm, somehow received a minus. It is in redux. Ok, according to you I made     let testsData = [];
    testsData = useSelector(state => state.fetchTestsData.testsData);  - with no luck it still claims it is undefinded. It was predictable, though. Why minus?

Comment: It isn't clear what could be the cause of the issue. Your question needs more details and context. [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) examples go a long way in getting issue resolution more quickly. Information about where `testsData` comes from and what touches it along the way to `useTable`.

Comment: @Drew Reese It is obvious.  I am retrieving data with   axios
            .get('http:/url/' )
            .then(response => {
                dispatch(fetchTestsData(response.data));
            });
    }, []);  and then I am receiveng them from redux     testsData = useSelector(state => state.fetchTestsData.testsData); that's all. no miracles. The question is how can I check for data presence, there sure should be some way to do it with react-table

Comment: Does `response.data` have defined table data in it when you dispatch to store it in state? Before that happens, what is the initial state value of `state.fetchTestsData.testsData` in the reducer. When is the axios request made to populate state? When I said give `testsData` an initial value I meant you can provide it as its source, being either a default value in state or a fallback value in the selector.

Comment: @DrewReese I'll better say that all worked in react-bootstrap-table2. All is ok in my reducer, initial state is []. Do you have a hint or a clue? Please don't keep me asking how many brackets I use, the question is, I repeat, how can I make react-table check for existance of data

Comment: Perhaps that other table library handled undefined values and other unhappy paths more gracefully. Super simple hack may be `useTable({columns, testsData || []})` Sorry you feel like I'm giving you the run around but you've not provided much other than the single piece of code that probably isn't the issue. When asking for help and people want to see your code and your response is, "no, it's all good", well that isn't very productive either. Another option is to use a debugger or dig though the react-table source code yourself to see why and where it breaks when you pass undefined data.

Comment: @DrewReese thank you for you effort. Super simple hack doesn't compile, anyway, I declared testsData = [] and passed it without fecthing new data, just empty array - it doesn't work.  I really don't know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this same exact issue trying to store the data with the state. Looking through the console log errors, I noticed that the error for undefined is referring to a variable named `data` within the plugin.

Since you changed that variable name to `testsData`, the plugin can't find what it is looking for. I realized that I need multiple tables on one page, so just using `data` won't cut it for me. When researching the API (https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/master/docs/api/useTable.md) I  discovered that you can pass in the key `data` for data but you will need to set that value to your `testsData` var on that same line and that should clear your error:

```
const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
} = useTable({columns, data: testsData});
```

Comment: I am running into this issue as well, pls is there any updated solution you're aware of, cuz after trying this it didnt work

Comment: @Paulliano - Sorry, we are still using v7.5.0 and it works for us in this fashion. Although, its been a while since I answered this question. From the contents of the question, you can always check if you have data before you pass it into the component. Then, if there's no data, then just show a skeleton component.